# Wrong reference for equation

Tags: pdftex

One of the equation environment, when cited by the `\eqref{}`, is shown like the sections (maybe is numbered as the section number instead of the formula number), not equation number! the code for the equation is as follows.

```
\begin{gather}\label{a67} 
a
\end{gather}
```

Then it is referenced by `\eqref{a67}` and what I get is like: (VIII). 
However, I expect to see something like: (67).

Comment: In normal circumstance it should be as you expected. However, we don't know anything about your `\documentclass{...}` nor used packages etc. So, please provide small but complete document, which we can inspect and compile.

Comment: So the equation is *numbered* `(67)` or is it numbered `(VIII)`? And you just want it to return the same number when referenced?

Comment: It is equation number (67), and the section number is (VIII). And yes.

Comment: @Hamid: And the equation number is visible? Are you using `\nonumber` or `\notag`? If so, can you please provide example code that replicates this behaviour as I can't replicate it with your current code snippet.

Comment: Actually yes that was the case and was solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question as unclear, as there is no indication of this in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, the equation is using `\nonumber` (or `\notag`) to disable the equation number, then the `\label` inside `gather` is just picking up the current section number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

% Section VIII
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\setcounter{section}{7}
\section{Section title}
\label{sec}

% Equation 67
\setcounter{equation}{66}
\begin{gather}\label{a67}
a
\end{gather}

% References:
Equation is \eqref{a67} and section is \ref{sec}.

\bigskip

Situation with wrong reference, if \verb|\nonumber| is used:

\begin{gather}\label{a68}
a \nonumber
\end{gather}

Equation is \emph{not} \eqref{a68}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: @71GA Which problem?